# Vertical stretch rephrasing

Tags: graphing-functions, quadratics, transformation, invariant-theory

From IGCSE Ch21 (quadratic) [errata](https://haesemathematics.com.au/media/W1siZiIsIjIwMTUvMDQvMjAvM2Y3N2VicHByal9pZ2NzZS5wZGYiXV0/igcse.pdf):

[image]

1. Is the second part supposed to be stretch of $y=-x^2$ and not $y=-ax^2$?
2. Can I say $y=ax^2$ is a vertical stretch of $y=x^2$ with invariant x-axis and scale factor $a$?
3. Can I say $y=ax^2$ is a vertical stretch of $y=\text{sgn}(a) x^2$ with invariant x-axis and scale factor $|a|$?

From IGCSE Ch21 (quadratic):

[image]

From IGCSE Ch20 (transformations):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Yes, provided you have defined negative scale factor.
3. Yes.

Comment: 1. Thanks 2. Thanks. What do you mean please? My understanding is that the statement holds true regardless of the sign of $a$. 3. Thanks

Comment: It is true regardless of the sign. All I mean is that your book seems to prefer positive scale factors, which made me think perhaps you haven't yet seen a definition of negative scale factor, but clearly you have

Comment: Thanks A. Goodier ^-^